# Using scroll() in Webdriver.io v4

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io, wdio-v4

My code logs into **mediawiki**'s beta site, goes to the *Preferences* page and attempts to click on a button at the bottom of the page.

I am trying to use [scroll()](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/utility/scroll.html) to achieve this since, running only `.click()` will result in an error, similar to the one below. The problem is that `.scroll()` doesn't seem to have any effect.

I'm using version 4 of WebdriverIO.

**What I've tried:**

1. I've tried this test with just `elem.click()`, without any scrolling and this resulted in a message similar to the one below where the element is not clickable.
2. When I run the code without `elem.click()`, the test passes, but I do not see the page scroll at all (*I add `browser.pause( 9000);` to the end to check*).
3. When I run `.scroll()` and pass it values, such as `elem.scroll(0,500)`, the page does scroll down, but not enough to see the actual element.
4. I've tried `.moveToObject()` which seems to scroll down the page, but not enough to see/interact with the element. I've also tried passing values to this, but it did not work.

---

```
it( 'should demonstrate the scroll command on the Preferences Page ', function () {
    // login 
    browser.url( 'https://en.wikipedia.beta.wmflabs.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page' );
    var loginName = $( '#wpName1' );
    var loginPass = $( '#wpPassword1' );
    var loginBtn = $( '#wpLoginAttempt' );
    loginName.setValue( 'Ephemeraltest' );
    loginPass.setValue( 'vagrant123' );
    loginBtn.click();

    // click button at bottom of preferences page
    browser.url( 'https://en.wikipedia.beta.wmflabs.org/wiki/Special:Preferences' );
    var elem = $( '#ooui-php-41' );

    elem.scroll();
    elem.click();

});
```

When I run the code, this error is reported:

> unknown error: Element ...
>   is not clickable at point (602, 571). Other element would receive the
>   click: ... running chrome Error:
>   An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>       at elementIdClick("0.7032716938931156-1") - click.js:20:22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `scrollIntoView`? If not try this: `selector` here would be `'#ooui-php-41'`

```
        browser.execute(elem => elem.scrollIntoView(), browser.element(selector).value);
```

Comment: They are using webdriverio version 4. Looks like scrollIntoView is available only in version 5 (https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/scrollIntoView.html), not version 4 (http://v4.webdriver.io/api.html).

Comment: Hi, The above example is written using `browser.execute()`(javascript executor). This command works in `v4`(because we are using it).

Comment: @NaveenThiyagarajan do you have solution for webdriveio v7. My scrollIntoView not working, when I watch not even scrolling. I tried 'await $(elemSelector).scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth', block:'center', inline: 'nearest'});'